# Recognize some words in an audio file

Tags: listening

In this [audio file](http://79.175.174.232/content/lessons/11/Intermediate1_2/unit%206/listening/listening.mp3), what does the woman say at 2:05:

> *drive* that little

or

> *tried* that little

How about the man at 2:47:

> finish it *off*

or

> finish it *up*

Source: *The ILI English Series, Intermediate 1, Unit 6*

Comment: "you drive that little..."  and "..and to finish it off"

Comment: You should quote the entire phrases since context might indicate which is more likely. Generally we don't *try* cars.

Comment: @user3169: Yes, you're right. "Drive" is meaningful in this context, but I don't know why it _sounds_ like "tried" to me even after listening to this file for many times!

Comment: You are right, it almost seems like she started to say the wrong word. Also, if you check the idiomatic expressions "finish it off" and "finish it up" you can get a better idea which fits here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The woman at 2:05 says

> drive that little

as she is referring to the size of the man's car. The context for this line is

> Man: Bad enough that there was water in my tent; I had to sleep in the car!
>
> Woman: You slept in the car? But you **drive that little-**
>
> Man: [interrupting] Yeah, I know. Not real comfortable.

## The man at 2:47 says

> finish it off